# Loop with sub assignment in parenthesis

Tags: python, loops, inline, variable-assignment

Is there a way to do this in Python? (I know you can do it Java.)

```
#PSEUDO CODE!!
while (inp = input()) != 'quit'
    print(inp)
```

E.g. In java the above pseudo code translates to:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
    String inp;
    while (!(inp = reader.readLine()).equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }
} catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println(io.toString());
}
```

---

EDIT:

... answered... but is this the only way?

```
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'quit':
        break
    print(inp)
print('eof')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

In this particular case, you could use a for-loop and [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
for inp in iter(input, 'quit'):
    print(inp)
```

`iter(input, 'quit')` will keep calling the `input` function and assigning its return value to `inp` as long as this value does not equal `'quit'`.

---

No, you cannot perform inline assignments in Python.  The [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) simply doesn't allow it (remember that assignments are statements in Python).

You can however do something like this:

```
while True:            # Loop continuously
    inp = input()      # Get the input
    if inp == 'quit':  # If it equals 'quit'...
        break          # ...then break the loop
    print(inp)         # Otherwise, continue with the loop
```

It is roughly equivalent to what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can define inp before your loop and reassign inside the while:

```
inp = None
while inp  != 'quit':
    print(inp)
    inp = input()
```

If you want to quit before entering the while loop set `inp = input()` initially.

```
inp = input()
while inp  != 'quit':
    print(inp)
    inp = input()
```

Comment: @PadriacCunningham Good optimization (I was almost there). But it still prints "quit" which is different from OP behaviour.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky, you can set the initial value to input which will quit before entering the while loop.